Homology of the Loop Space of $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2$
Since $M = \mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2$ is rationally hyperbolic, it is known that the betti numbers of its loop space grow exponentially as a function of degree.
Does anyone have any ideas about how to calculate or approximate the exponent of this growth? I am looking for leads even if you don't know that your answer will work definitively.

Theorem 3.3 on pg.30 of Sebastian Chenery's thesis gives a complete description of the homotopy type of $\Omega M$ in terms certain loops and double loops of copies of $S^2$'s.

@Tyrone Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately that theorem requires a complex with dimension $2n$ with $n \notin {2,4,8}$ which rules out this manifold. The thesis looks relevant, I will search it for helpful results.

Sorry, I missed the extra requirement. Theorem 3.9 of Sebastian's thesis is specifically for the 4-dimensional case, but it's a little bit more complicated. The homology groups of $\Omega M$ can still be read off, but they are a little more difficult to extract.
